# Retrieving user info in oauth2 resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, gitlab, spring-security-oauth2

I've been developing a web app with OAuth2 sign-in and I'm not quite sure I should identify the user based on his access_token in my resource server. I think I'm missing some crucial step or I did something wrong in my implementation. I use Gitlab as OAuth2.0 provider, Spring boot as API and resource server and of course a web client.

Resource server config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class MyApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApi.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${client.address}")
    private String clientAddress;

    @Value("${oauth2.gitlab.client.id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oauth2.gitlab.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${oauth2.gitlab.check_token}")
    private String checkTokenUri;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
                .resourceId("user")
                .tokenServices(tokenService());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setClientId(clientId);
        tokenService.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUri);
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

I overrode RemoteTokenServices and the endpoint I use is /oauth/introspect. With that setup, every HTTP request coming to my API must be authenticated and must have valid access_token. The thing is that this endpoint returns the following response. It seems that based on that I can only check whether the request is authenticated, not who is the owner of it and I should somehow start using user_info_endpoint in my resource server. Can anyone put me on a right track?

```
{
    "active": true,
    "scope": "api",
    "client_id": "my-client-api",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "exp": 0,
    "iat": 1606119799
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate users, look at [GitLab as OpenID Connect identity provider](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/openid_connect_provider.html) instead. OpenID Connect is a profile implemented on top of OAuth2 for the purpose of authenticating users.

Comment: I think the request is already authenticated, I'm just missing the information about the auth user in Prinicipal / SecurityContextHolder and I don't know how exactly should I set these.